# How to turn an array of objects in to a list with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

```
R.pipe(
  R.map(R.any(R.isNil(R.pickAll(['a','d']))))
)([{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4},{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}])
```

Results in an array with two objects that evaluate to false because neither object isNil. I instead want to evaluate the values in a single list instead and see if any are Nil.  I've tried using flatten but get a 'n.apply is not a function error'.

Comment: Can you clarify what output are you looking for?

Comment: More clarification would be welcome. The question title is confusing, because neither native JS nor Ramda has a concept of an independent `List` (i.e. of a thing called `List` that is not actually a JS `Array`).

Comment: @tex: Ramda's documentation uses "list" as shorthand for the closest native equivalent: dense (i.e. not sparse) arrays.  I agree, though, about the need for clarification.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm aware of that. What I find confusing is that the asker has asked how to turn an array into a list, when they're not really independent concepts.

Comment: @vlaz looking for a true or false output.

Comment: @ael - please add an example of the requested output.

Comment: @ael so, if there is any object that *doesn't* have `a` or `d` you expect it to be `false`, while if it has both, it should be `true`, is that correct?

Comment: @OriDrori I believe your answer will work, with some adjusting for a true or false output. I think i could just replace reject with any.

Comment: @VLAZ not quite. i want to know if either of those properties have a null or undefined value.

Comment: OK, so given an input of `[{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4},{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}, ,{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: null}]` the result should be `[true, true, false]`?

Comment: @ael Check my second snippet - I think it does what you're asking.

Comment: @ael if performance is a concern, the code in my second snippet (which I added over half an hour ago) should perform better depending on `props` and `any(isNil)`.

Comment: @vlaz no i would want to get just a single false output. thats why i was trying to turn the array of objects into an array of just values from certain properties.

Comment: @ael ah, I see. I got it - I thought that the check was supposed to be for *each* object but it's just collective for *all* of them.

Comment: @ael see my third snippet returning a single `true` or `false` value based on whether any properties `a` or `d` in any of the objects is Nil.

Answer (score 1):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, you want to keep all objects for which property `a` or `d` is `Nil` (Ramda-speak for `null` or `undefined`). Please correct me if I've misunderstood.

Assuming my interpretation is correct, this should do the trick:

```js
const data = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

const result = R.filter(
  R.either(R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'a'), R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'd')),
  data
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If, instead, you want a new array that has `true` in the position of any object for which `a` or `d` is Nil, this should do the trick:

```js
const data = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

const result = R.map(
  R.either(R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'a'), R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'd')),
  data
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

To return a single boolean value (`true` if no objects have properties `a` or `d` = Nil, `false` otherwise):

```js
const data = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

const result = R.all(
  R.either(R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'a'), R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'd')),
  data
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping that when I got back to this, the requirements would be more clear.  But if the expected result is as simple as it seems, then I would not use any Ramda functions for it.  (Note: I'm one of Ramda's creators and a big fan, but I only use it when it adds clarity.)  Does this do what you want?

```js
const missingProp =  (props) => (obj) => 
  props .some (prop => !(prop in obj))

const anyMissing = (props) => (xs) => 
  xs .some (missingProp (props))

const data1 = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]
const data2 = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

console .log (anyMissing (['a', 'd']) (data1)) //=> true
console .log (anyMissing (['a', 'd']) (data2)) //=> false
```

Of course you could inline that helper function instead:

```js
const anyMissing = (props) => (xs) => 
  xs .some (obj => props .some (prop => !(prop in obj)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of boolean result that indicates if at least one of the values is nil, you can achieve this by getting the values with [R.props](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props), and checking if any of them is nil:

```js
const { map, pipe, props, any, isNil } = R

const fn = map(pipe(props(['a','d']), any(isNil)))

const data = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

To get an array of the actual values, you can use [R.chain](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) with [R.props](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#props) to get a flat list of `a` and `d` values, and then use [R.reject](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) with [R.isNil](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isNil) to remove all `undefined` values.

```js
const { pipe, chain, props, reject, isNil } = R

const fn = pipe(
  chain(props(['a', 'd'])), // get all values of a & d in a single array
  reject(isNil) // remove all nil values
)

const data = [{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```